# Using NSIS Math Library: How to perform 'Power to'

Tags: installation, nsis

I am attempting to use the [NSIS Math Library](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Math_plug-in) to perform a `Power` calculation. I'm having alot of difficulty working out the Math library syntax.

How can I perform this calculation in NSIS: `h ^= g;`

```
Var h # example variables
Var g
Var a

# I am attempting to perform the following calculations in NSIS.
# I'm not sure how exactly to do it using the math library syntax?
# Do I need to include the Math.nsh library to use it?
# h ^= g;

# My attempt:
Math::Script "a = $h; b = $g; c = ?? a = Power(a,b,c); R0 = a"
```

Comment: Just to make sure, `^=` from what language? In C/C++ `^` is XOR, and `^=` is an XOR with an assignment.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson its C++. I thought its was a power to but you're right its a XOR. How do you perform a XOR in NSIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite similar to C/C++, to define a function that calculates XOR and returns the result, try;

```
Math::Script 'myxor(h,g) (h^g);'
```

After that myxor(3,2) will give you `3 XOR 2` = 1.